# One class for the database and for the form?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a class called Domains with properties - domain, user, start date, due date... I use it once for creating the database with annotations, and once for creating a form in which take place only a few of the properties in the class Domains - for example start and due date (the form is used for update of the information). I create the form in this way:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('start_date', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd')); ...
```

My question is: is it possible to put both kind of annotations - for validation and for the database like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
 */
protected $start_date;
```

If no will it be possible if the one is with annotations and the other with a .yml file? And if yes is it a good practice at all? I did it because a lot of the properties are the same - only the class which shlould be used with the database has more of them and it seems pointless to write two class part of which are identical. I thought about inheritance, too but the problem still stays. Please tell me what will fit the best! :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put both kinds of annotations. Do it like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
 */
protected $start_date;
```

Comment: Thank you very much once again! :) I really appreciate your help!